# Enrich-My-Library optimization

Tags: c#, scala, optimization, extension-methods, enrich-my-library

Disclaimer: I came to Scala from C#, where I really appreciated LINQ.
Therefore, I immediately felt at home with iterators and sequences. I missed yield "C# style", but I was able to cook my own with continuations... even if it pays a performance penalty.

Now, when I miss some method over collections in C#, I just define it as an extension method, and the compiler does a very nice job of treating code efficiently. 
In Scala, I use the <s>Pimp</s> enrich My Library approach, but I am a little bit worried about performances.

Contrary to my "yield iterator", however, this is a recognized and common patter. Does the Scala compiler optimize it, removing the creation of the temporary object?

```
class RichFoo(f: Foo) {
  def baz = f.bar()
  def baz2 = f.bar() * 2
}
object RichFoo {
  implicit def foo2Rich(f: Foo) = new RichFoo(f)
}

// on the caller side
val f : Foo = ....
f.baz
f.baz2
// this translates, literally, to new RichFoo(f).baz, new RichFoo(f).baz2
```

If not, why? It looks like a good and safe optimization to me. Can I "hint" or "force" the compiler in the right direction? Which faster alternatives are there?

I would like to use the pattern for my collection of algorithms over iterators/iterable, so I can write them as filter/map/etc `collection.baz(lambda).bar(lambda2)` but I am afraid it will prove to be too "heavy". (Compared to the more efficient/direct, but ugly `bar(lambda2, baz(lambda, collection)`)

Comment: The fastest alternative to the date is to use **implicit value classes** (available in 2.10) so compiler will try as hard as it can to elide those *rich* wrapper classes and to inline methods you've introduced.

Comment: @om-nom-nom sounds good... are there any posts/papers/... where can I read how is it done and which are the performance benefits? Also, what can I do if I'm stuck with 2.9.1?

Comment: Aside from pretty good spec on [value classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/value-classes.html) and [implicit classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/implicit-classes.html) you may [start with this post](http://java.dzone.com/articles/scala-210-%E2%80%93-or-why-you-will). Sadly looks like unlike [another proposal](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/futures-promises.html) those two features won't be backported to 2.9.4 (which is binary compatible with 2.9.1 and planned to come out in august).

Comment: @om-nom-nom thank you, the spec on value classes is what I was looking for. Am I right that this optimization will also work for native types? I'm thinking of Int here (without boxing?), or Array[T]?

Comment: As @RégisJean-Gilles pointed to me some time ago, although this feature named *value* classes, it should work with both primitive and reference types underneath, so looks like pimping Array[T] should be fine.

Comment: The standard name for this pattern is now **enrich** my library.  Which, aside from the possibly offensive former reference, also more closely matches the naming used in code (i.e. RichX).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @om-nom-nom comments, the solution here (in 2.10) is to use an implicit value class.

```
implicit class RichFoo(val f : Foo) extends AnyVal {
  def baz = f.bar()
  def bax = f.bar()
}
```

`RichFoo` exists now at compile time, but at runtime this is optimized into a static method call, and so should impose no performance penalty.

See [Value classes (SIP)](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/value-classes.html)

See also Mark Harrah's [Introduction to Value Classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) which gives a good overview from the usage perspective.